# What are all of the bits for in Winapi button states?

Tags: winapi, button

The MSDN documentation says that the elements of button state are focus, push, and check.
Looking into the header we see:

```
BST_CHECKED        0x0001
BST_INDETERMINATE  0x0002
BST_PUSHED         0x0004
BST_FOCUS          0x0008
```

but when I push a button in my application Button_GetState yields the integer value 108 (then 104 if I drag outside of the button). So here we have the first four bits accounted for, but what about after that? What about 16,32, 64? My button is not one that uses check state as far as I can tell, yet I still see these being used.

In short, what are the other individual bits doing?

Comment: I could find these ones, but not 0x100 : BST_HOT=0x0200, BST_DROPDOWNPUSHED=0x0400

Comment: I guess it is an internal, not documented state.

Comment: interesting... which file holds BST_HOT? I saw that in the msdn documentation but did not found it in any of the headers I am using. Maybe there could be other clues there

Comment: I think it's commctrl.h

Comment: It's not clear how you get these values. Show your code. Do you mean `0x108` and `0x104`?

Comment: @Barmak Surely he must do.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani i meant the integer value 108, so 0X6C. Edited to include that detail

Comment: Yes, that's a mystery. I see that in Windows 10 as well. You are supposed to use the `&` operator against the documented constants. The other value `0x60` is not documented and is probably for windows internal use.